# Trying to get a 403 error code over a socket

Tags: python-3.x, sockets

I have an python socket programming assignment. One of the tasks is to prevent a malicious attack by preventing any URL that contains /../

In my code below I have commented out the line of code that I expected to return a 403 Forbidden error. But when that line of code is active, nothing really happens. I am executing the code from command line using curl (--path-as-is) to ensure the /../ is not stripped out (eg. like Chrome does). But when this line of code is active nothing is returned in the command prompt. If the line of code is commented out, then curl returns a 52 error code. But ultimately I would like to get a 403 error code returned.

```
while True:
    print('Ready to serve....')
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept() #Fill in code to get a connection
    try:
        message = connectionSocket.recv(1024).decode() #Fill in code to read GET request
        filename = message.split()[1]
        if("/../" in filename): #security code to see if there is a /../ in the filename URL
            #connectionSocket.send('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden\r\n'.encode()) # Send HTTP header line(s) into socket
            connectionSocket.close()
            continue;
```

Comment: Is this solved? If so please accept the answer to show that it's been solved.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that when you have that line active, what it would do is send a 403 error and close the socket connection. However, you are not breaking out of the loop and so this will carry on running in your while loop without any output. Try changing `continue` to `break`

```
while True:
    print('Ready to serve....')
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept() #Fill in code to get a connection
    try:
        message = connectionSocket.recv(1024).decode() #Fill in code to read GET request
        filename = message.split()[1]
        if("/../" in filename): #security code to see if there is a /../ in the filename URL
            connectionSocket.send('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden\r\n'.encode()) # Send HTTP header line(s) into socket
            connectionSocket.close()
            break;#exits the while loop
```

> Error 52 returned by CURL

Curl gives this error when there is no reply from a server since it is an error for HTTP not to respond to anything to a request. This makes sense since you are not sending/receiving anything via the socket as the line is commented out.

Answer (score 0):

```
#connectionSocket.send('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden\r\n'.encode()) # Send HTTP header line(s) into socket
```

That would not be a valid HTTP response. You are missing the final `\r\n` at the end of the HTTP header:

```
connectionSocket.send(b"HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden\r\n\r\n")
```